# Matrix of AtomicLong

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, cpu-cache, compare-and-swap

I have a large matrix of AtomicLong that is a central structure in my algorithm. 
I wonder if it is a better strategy to use an array of long and to use the CAS method directly in my class. I think this could improve:

1. Memory usage: array of primitive being much compact than array of objects
2. Cache behaviour: less indirection (I'm not sure yet if I will have a very predictible array traversal)

Has anybody any experience in this ? Before to start coding I would rather have some feedback on this strategy.

Comment: tell a bit more about the algorythm, how do you access elements and how do you update them

Comment: I have a large matrix of long where each element may be accessed and modified concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, few hours later. 
This option can't work as I wanted since it is impossible to declare an array of volatile variable, see the excellent post here: http://jeremymanson.blogspot.fr/2009/06/volatile-arrays-in-java.html

The good way, is to replace my matrix of AtomicLong by an array of [AtomicLongArray](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLongArray.html)